# Javascript; very simple Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, slide

I want to create a simple slideshow just using Javascript.

Im almost finish, but im in trouble.

I want to appear Third and Fourth.

```
<article>
<div>
<ul class="slide" id="slide1">First</ul>
<ul class="slide" id="slide2">Twice</ul>
<ul class="slide" id="slide3">Third</ul>
<ul class="slide" id="slide4">Fourth</ul>
<li class="control" id="back" style="float: left;">Back</li>
<li class="control" id="next" style="float: right;">Next</li>
</div>
</article>
```

When i click next #slide lose opacity and font-size will reset to 0px.

```
var next = document.getElementById('next');
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
if (document.getElementById('slide1').style.opacity = "1"){
document.getElementById('slide1').style.opacity = "0";
document.getElementById('slide1').style.fontSize = "0px";
document.getElementById('slide2').style.opacity = "1";
document.getElementById('slide2').style.WebkitTransition = 'opacity 2s';
document.getElementById('slide2').style.fontSize = "16px";
}
}, false);
var back = document.getElementById('back');
back.addEventListener('click', function() {
if (document.getElementById('slide2').style.opacity = "1"){
document.getElementById('slide2').style.opacity = "0";
document.getElementById('slide2').style.fontSize = "0px";
document.getElementById('slide1').style.opacity = "1";
document.getElementById('slide1').style.WebkitTransition = 'opacity 2s';
document.getElementById('slide1').style.fontSize = "16px";
}
}, false);
```

But i want a third or fourth content. This will directly appear when i use this in same way. When you click next u will appear directly Third. But it it have to appear Twice before.

**FIDDLE without third content
[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/AhT4B/)**

**FIDDE with third content
[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/AhT4B/1/)**

I need to fix that...

Comment: Your markup is invalid. `<ul>` should only contain `<li>` nodes, and `<li>` must be inside `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Comment: so what you actually want. Can you make it little more specific!

Comment: Please put the question or issue directly in the question.  The fiddles may also go away in the future as some point and also consider adding to the title which is currently too generic to help other users that just see the title.  Thanks!

Comment: I want when I click Next firstly appear Twice and then Third.
But it will appear directly. @codeSpy

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, you needed to use the condition:

```
if(document.getElementById('slide1').style.opacity==1)
```

instead of:

```
if(document.getElementById('slide1').style.opacity = "1")
```

for each slide transition.

Also, the first slide begins with an empty opacity style ("" instead of 1), so I also added an identical slide1 transition for the condition:

```
if(document.getElementById('slide1').style.opacity=="")
```

I also went ahead and added the fourth slide for you.

Here is your completed code:

```
        <article>
            <div>

            <ul class="slide" id="slide1">First</ul>
            <ul class="slide" id="slide2">Twice</ul>
            <ul class="slide" id="slide3">Third</ul>
            <ul class="slide" id="slide4">Fourth</ul>
            <li class="control" id="back" style="float: left;">Back</li><li class="control" id="next" style="float: right;">Next</li>
            </div>
        </article>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px groove;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    zoom: 1;
}
article {
    position: relative;
    background-size: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    height: calc(100% - 50px)\9;
    height: calc(100% - 50px)\0/;
    color: black;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.65) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0  7px 7px -7px black;
    box-shadow: inset 0  7px 7px -7px black;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0  7px 7px -7px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0  7px 7px -7px black;
}
div {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    top: 100px;
    padding: 100px;
}
.slide{
    margin-left: 100px;

}
#slide2, #slide3, #slide4 {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 0px;

}
.control {
    display: inline;
    position: static;
}
```

javascript:

```
var next = document.getElementById('next');
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
if (document.getElementById('slide1').style.opacity==""){
document.getElementById('slide1').style.opacity = "0";
document.getElementById('slide1').style.fontSize = "0px";
document.getElementById('slide2').style.opacity = "1";                document.getElementById('slide2').style.WebkitTransition= 'opacity 2s';                document.getElementById('slide2').style.fontSize = "16px";
}
else if (document.getElementById('slide1').style.opacity==1){
document.getElementById('slide1').style.opacity = "0";
document.getElementById('slide1').style.fontSize = "0px";
document.getElementById('slide2').style.opacity = "1";                document.getElementById('slide2').style.WebkitTransition= 'opacity 2s';                document.getElementById('slide2').style.fontSize = "16px";
}
else if (document.getElementById('slide2').style.opacity==1){
document.getElementById('slide2').style.opacity = "0";
document.getElementById('slide2').style.fontSize = "0px";
document.getElementById('slide3').style.opacity = "1";                document.getElementById('slide3').style.WebkitTransition= 'opacity 2s';                document.getElementById('slide3').style.fontSize = "16px";
}
else if (document.getElementById('slide3').style.opacity==1){
document.getElementById('slide3').style.opacity = "0";
document.getElementById('slide3').style.fontSize = "0px";
document.getElementById('slide4').style.opacity = "1";                document.getElementById('slide4').style.WebkitTransition= 'opacity 2s';                document.getElementById('slide4').style.fontSize = "16px";
}


}, false);
var back = document.getElementById('back');
back.addEventListener('click', function() {
if (document.getElementById('slide2').style.opacity==1){
document.getElementById('slide2').style.opacity = "0";
document.getElementById('slide2').style.fontSize = "0px";
document.getElementById('slide1').style.opacity = "1";
document.getElementById('slide1').style.WebkitTransition = 'opacity 2s';
document.getElementById('slide1').style.fontSize = "16px";
}
else if (document.getElementById('slide3').style.opacity==1){
document.getElementById('slide3').style.opacity = "0";
document.getElementById('slide3').style.fontSize = "0px";
document.getElementById('slide2').style.opacity = "1";
document.getElementById('slide2').style.WebkitTransition = 'opacity 2s';
document.getElementById('slide2').style.fontSize = "16px";
}
else if (document.getElementById('slide4').style.opacity==1){
document.getElementById('slide4').style.opacity = "0";
document.getElementById('slide4').style.fontSize = "0px";
document.getElementById('slide3').style.opacity = "1";
document.getElementById('slide3').style.WebkitTransition = 'opacity 2s';
document.getElementById('slide3').style.fontSize = "16px";
}
}, false);
```

Comment: well and after fourth? :)

Comment: What do you mean? Like if you wanted to add a fifth?

Comment: no when the fourth is displayed and u click netxt it should displayed first